# how to add windows 8 entry to grub after boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-8

I installed ubuntu 14.04 in a dual boot (with windows 8.1) but my pc directly boots into ubuntu. For that I did a boot-repair->recommended repair. But all I got was grub menu with an option to boot to ubuntu.

here is the ubuntu pastebin file I got at the end of boot-repair:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8433985/

It seems to identify the windows 8 partition, but I don't know how to add an entry for the same in the grub menu.

I searched the net but I couldn't understand the procedure (I am a newbie..)

So pl help me guys..

Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

According to your link [http://paste.ubuntu.com/8433985/] you installed Ubuntu in `/dev/sda5`.

Then do the following steps to reinstall grub and recover Windows entry:

#### Boot from live CD/Flash and do steps:

Open Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the commands one by one.

1. Mount `/dev/sda5` by the following commands:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev;do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i";done
   ```
2. Now we mounted the `/dev/sda5`. just run below command to switch to `root` directory of Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
3. And run below command to install grub to main partition `/dev/sda`:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
4. Update grub and exit and reboot your system. it will fix.

   ```
   update-grub
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```

I hope this helps.